# Visual Studio Empty Cordova Multi Device Hybrid App Build Failure [error code 8]

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Having tried to follow all advices, remedies and workarounds including removing and reinstalling the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio CPT1 I still can't seem to do a successful build of the included "Blank App (Apache Cordova)" project.

Build ends consistently in one single error:

```
The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7
\IDE\Extensions\k04kuuo3.ie0\packages\vs-mda\install" "C:\Program Files (x86)
\nodejs\" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7
\IDE\Extensions\k04kuuo3.ie0\packages\vs-mda"" exited with code 8.

File    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets
Line    108
Column  5
Project BlankCordovaApp1
```

Environment settings:

```
ADT_HOME    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
ANT_HOME    C:\apache-ant-1.9.3
GIT_HOME    C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
JAVA_HOME   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
PATH    %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ADT_HOME%\platform-tools;%ADT_HOME%\tools;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows 
    Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\
(contains no reference to "Platform")
```

Your kind help is very much appreciated, Thanks 
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the light bulb went on for me: The problem was the install batch files not being able to locate xcopy.exe and therefore the simple remedy was to just extend the path variable with

    %SystemRoot%\system32;

The build now runs without further errors.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this on one of my PCs and here's how I got it fixed:

1. Quit Visual Studio
2. Open the Android SDK manager by typing the Windows key and then "SDK manager", hit enter
3. Install Android Build Tools Rev 19 by checking the box next to it and clicking Install packages
4. Accept the license
5. Open Visual Studio and your project, then run it again

Jordan (Microsoft, Multi-Device Hybrid Apps tools team)

Comment: Thanks Jordan, Unfortunately this didn't do the trick for me as I already followed this and other advice found at [link](http://goo.gl/2n5HPY) - I also tried switching to 64-bit version of nodejs instead of the x86 version. (This because the above error message seems to point to the problem potentially being connected to a failed installation of **C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\** - But still no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jordan and Ian.

I ended up doing both.

I ran the Android SDK manager to install the Android Build Tools Rev 19 as well as some other updates.

I also added "%SystemRoot%\system32;" to the PATH environment variable.

Everything running as it should.