# MDHA build failed

Tags: visual-studio, multi-device-hybrid-apps

please help with this build problem. i have checked system variables. they are correct like priyank mentioned in other answers

1. Warning  1   The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets 90  5   SampleHybridApp
2. Error    2   Cannot find module 'config-chain'   Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\EXEC  1   1   SampleHybridApp
3. Error    3   The command ""C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Android" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "SampleHybridApp" --buildServerUrl "" --buildTarget "AndroidEmulator"" exited with code 8.    C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets   68  5   SampleHybridApp

Comment: Can you try the fix here and see if it works for you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041159/unable-to-build-cordova-project-in-visual-studio

Comment: I tried 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041159/unable-to-build-cordova-project-in-visual-studio

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668519/an-error-occurred-building-visual-studio-cordova-app-using-multi-device-hybrid-a

Repairing VS2013.2
Repairing CTP1.1
Several Reboots

but problem remains