# The command x prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName y exited with code 8

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, ant, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am trying to start developing app with multi-device-hybrid-app for visual studio.

After setting all system variables my errors are these

1. Error   4   The command ""C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "name" --language "en-US"" exited with code 8.
2. Error   2   executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
3. Error   3   C:\Users\userName.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8

what I have done

1. Read all questions about this argument in SO without success
2. Added **ADT_HOME** with value C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
3. Added **ANT_HOME** with value C:\apache-ant-1.9.3
4. Added **JAVA_HOME** with value C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71
5. Edited Path system variable as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668519/an-error-occurred-building-visual-studio-cordova-app-using-multi-device-hybrid-a) question
6. Deleted the **bld** folder from the project as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041159/unable-to-build-cordova-project-in-visual-studio) question
7. Updated Android API from Android SDK manager (I have 8,10 and from 16 to 21)

I don't know what to try, I have tryed everything (reinstall VisualStudio and Java from zero)

I have VisualStudio 2013 ultimate with Windows 7 pro

Can anyone help me?

UPDATE:
this is my Multi Device Hybrid Apps enviroment configuration

[image]

Comment: I've updated the question. Let me know if you have any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one day spent looking for missing variables to set I discover that the problem was caused by a missing information in `Path` variable.

Just add `%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;`, restart VisualStudio and everything works great!