# Why do I get errors when building a hybrid app

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

When I'm trying to build and deploy a new hybrid app template (with no changes done) build fails and I receive this output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  C:\Users\YA\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(208,5): error : "MySQL" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(208,5): error : ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(208,5): error : "MySQL" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(208,5): error : ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\SLSJAGN5.MZC\packages\vs-mda
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Maybe errors text is in Russian, but I can't figure out how to change encoding in Output Window. I'm using Russian Windows 7, but VS (2013 Community) was intentionally set up in English without any language pack. Never had any problems with Russian text in Output before on other PCs.  Also, I've checked all environment variables mentioned in some other topics related to Cordova, they seems to be OK.

Any suggestions how to track and solve this?

**EDIT**: As initial system isn't available for now, I've tried it on my home system. I'm receiving another output but with the same result - build fails:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BlankCordovaApp4, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  d:\mydocuments\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp4\BlankCordovaApp4>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.26 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0N5RFQMM.AHA\packages\vs-mda
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

System is Windows 7 x64 HP. I've checked there was no failed dependency report. Still no result. I've tried to follow this [Unable to build Cordova project in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041159/unable-to-build-cordova-project-in-visual-studio), but no luck also. And no errors in Error List window.

*sighs*

Suggestions, pleeease?

Comment: Redirect the build log to file if log file is not created. Set the build log verbosity to diagnostic under Tools-->Options-->Projects and Solutions-->Build and Run and post the build log content.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by removing doing what is said here: ['MySQL' is not recognized as an internal command (Apache Cordova for visual studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366873/mysql-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-command-apache-cordova-for-visual-stud) and also removing `C:\Users\Miquel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\*.*` and `C:\Users\Miquel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\*.*`

Then in cmd I went to `C:\Users\Miquel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda` and ran:

```
npm install
```