# Apache Cordova: Mysql is not reconized as an internal or external command?

Tags: mysql, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have just install visual studio 2015 with apache cordova. By creating a blank app when I run it I got error "Mysql is not reconized as an internal or external command" and other error as[image]

I found following solution of forum which does not worked for me.[Click to open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366873/mysql-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-command-apache-cordova-for-visual-stud).

I added the environment variables and mysql is working in cmd.[image]

Any solution.

Comment: so what is the problem now really? You pathed and found it. Your first picture is meaningless in my opinion, other than to show us a code window unrelated to the Error messages

Comment: The first is showing error while and the second picture I have uploaded to show that mysql is working in cmd and the other forum was showing that adding path variable will solve problem.

Comment: ok. do you still have a problem, or is it solved. If you have a problem, please detail it better

Answer (score 0):

I recommend 2 way to resolve it.
 - Please commit MySQL folder in PATH.
 - Update or reinstall MySQL
It's work for me!