# cordova Hybrid APP build error with vs2013

Tags: installation, visual-studio-cordova

I tried build blank cordova hybrid app with vs2013 , but got some error

(1) Cannot find module 'lru-cache'

(2) The command ""C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "BlankCordovaApp2"" exited with code 8.

What's i missing?

Dev Tool : vs2013 up2 and install cordova perview
OS : win 8.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Empty Cordova Multi Device Hybrid App Build Failure \[error code 8\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849006/visual-studio-empty-cordova-multi-device-hybrid-app-build-failure-error-code-8)

Comment: Thanks , but i tried that ,still error . The PATH environment variable , i set for system PATH variable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know if the project build was interrupted midway?

This looks like a node acquisition issue. If any of you run into this issue, could you run `npm install lru-cache` and let us know if that fixes it?

Thanks!
Avani

Comment: Upgrade to VS2013 UP3 and Cordova CTP 2.0 . This problem is fixed . Thanks Avani